# How to insert data automatically into a foreign key in mysql?

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have two tables `bid` and `instalment`. `bid_id`is the `PK` of `bid`and it is `FK` of instalment. Now , acc. to definitions , it should automatically accommodate data in `FK` ?

[image: database schema]

But when I insert data, my `FK`remains empty. Is there something I forgot to do or to attach in the tables ? I mean how my `FK` will automatically accommodate data (i.e., `bid_id`) from bid ?

[image: Inserted data]

Comment: In general, for each row inserted into the parent you get the LAST_INSERT_ID and then insert it into the foreign key,all of these put into a transaction to guarantee consistency.

Answer (score -1):

foreign keys are to make sure data consistency i.e. for validation but not data data auto fill (yes impact on update/delete on clild based on master).

You can check details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)-

Comment: That means I need to enter the `bid_id` in `ìnstalment` manually ?

Comment: yes and it will be in sync so that corresponding master id will be inserting in child also in correct manner, may be you should need to do it in transaction first insert new row in master then get last_insert_id() and put it into child table.....

Comment: can you please write the syntax for last_insert_id() . should I write 
`insert into instalment (bid_id) = (select last_insert_id(bid_id) from bid)` or do I need to write something else ?

Comment: just insert a record in master table as usual and after that use following command to get last inserted primary key "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"

Comment: Want to know reason of -ve marking to know where I was wrong... :)